# My download files keep opening on notpead

Tags: windows-10

I accidentally opened a file with notepad and now every time I download an app or a file it opens with notepad ONLY and it's frustrating me please help me with this, I'm using windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your downloads tab in your file explorer. Find the file you downloaded. Right click >> Open with >> Choose another app >> Select the program you want to use and select use this program every time.